# Magento2: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile, mongo

On running di:compile command I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in /var/www/html/monotaro/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php:116
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/monotaro/vendor/monotaro-global/mongo/module-mongo-core/Model/Client/ClientFactory.php(37): MongoDB\Client->__construct('mongodb://mage_...', Array, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/monotaro/vendor/monotaro-global/mongo/module-mongo-core/Model/Db.php(66): MonotaROGlobal\MongoCore\Model\Client\ClientFactory->create(Object(MonotaROGlobal\MongoCore\Model\Client\FactoryOptions))
#2 /var/www/html/monotaro/vendor/monotaro-global/mongo/module-mongo-core/Model/Db.php(76): MonotaROGlobal\MongoCore\Model\Db->getConnection()
#3 /var/www/html/monotaro/vendor/monotaro-global/mongo/module-mongo-core/Model/Adapter/Adapter.php(25): MonotaROGlobal\MongoCore\Model\Db->getDb()
#4 /var/www/html/monotaro/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(121): MonotaROGlobal\MongoCore\Model\Adapter\Adapter->__construct(Object(MonotaROGlobal\MongoCore\Model\Db))
#5 /var/w in /var/www/html/monotaro/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php on line 116
```

MongoDB driver is already installed and running on my local system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry can't comment yet, but have you check if the requested class `MongoDB\Driver\Manager` were really existing in the module ? It would not be the first time I encounter a contributor module with location errors, also check you are using the contributor stable version of the module.